# pandas keep rows based on column values for repeated values

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas data frame and I have a list of values. I want to keep all the rows from my original DF that have a certain column value belonging to my list of values. However my list that I want to choose my rows from have repeated values. Each time I encounter the same values again I want to add the rows with that column values again to my new data frame.

lets say my frames name is: with_prot_choice_df and my list is: with_prot_choices

if I issue the following command:

```
with_prot_choice_df = with_df[with_df[0].isin(with_prot_choices)]
```

then this will only keep the rows once (as if for only unique values in the list).

I don't want to do this with for loops since I will repeat the process many times and it will be extremely time consuming. 
Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks.

I'm adding an example here:

let's say my data frame is:

```
col1   col2
a      1
a      6
b      2
c      3
d      4
```

and my list is: 
    lst = [a,b,a,a]

I want my new data frame, new_df to be:
    new_df

```
col1   col2
a      1
a      6
b      2
a      1
a      6
a      1
a      6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need `reindex`

```
df.set_index('col1').reindex(lst).reset_index()
Out[224]: 
  col1  col2
0    a     1
1    b     2
2    a     1
3    a     1
```

Updated

```
df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'col1':lst}).reset_index()).sort_values('index').drop('index',1)
Out[236]: 
  col1  col2
0    a     1
3    a     6
6    b     2
1    a     1
4    a     6
2    a     1
5    a     6
```

Comment: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: I think this error is raised because my data frame has repetitions for values of the first column. Here I eddited the example in my original post

Comment: beatiful, runs in less than a sec over thousands of rows. Thanks a ton would have never figured this out.

Comment: @user3289556 yw~ :-) happy coding